# searching an element in list of list

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list like:

```
list=[[lsn,tid,status,type,item,AFIM,BFIM],[1,1,Active,Read,X,-,-],[2,1,Active,Write,X,2,0],....and so on]
```

Now I have one variable

```
tid=1
```

and I want to search that list in 'list' where tid matches and status should be 'Write'. I was trying like this but no result at all.....

```
for id, stat in list/enumerate(list):
    if id == tid and stat == 'Write':
        print list
```

Does splitting the list help??

Comment: You should consider using a list of dictionaries rather than list of lists. You've effectively got key-value pairs.

Comment: Also don't call your variable `list` as it masks the builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just edited to post here otherwise i'm aware of that.Thanks any ways.

Comment: what is `list/enumerate`?

Comment: it means like I have tried with both ways list and enumerate(list)...
Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
l = [["lsn","tid","status","type","item","AFIM","BFIM"],
     [1,1,"Active","Read","X","-","-"],
     [2,1,"Active","Write","X","2","0"]]

for row in l:
    if row[1] == 1 and row[3] == 'Write':
        print(row)

# will print ...
# [2, 1, 'Active', 'Write', 'X', '2', '0']
```

You could also use [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
import collections
Row = collections.namedtuple('Row', 'lsn tid status type item AFIM BFIM')

for row in map(lambda row: Row(*row), l):
    if row.tid == 1 and row.type == 'Write':
        print(row)

# will print ...
# Row(lsn=2, tid=1, status='Active', type='Write', item='X', AFIM='2', BFIM='0')
```

Comment: This should work but dictionary is the best way to go about it. This will cause the loop to also iterate the first list. Change `"tid"` to 1 and `"type"` to `"Write"` to see the effect.

Comment: @Yax, the header could be skipped easily by using `l[1:]` instead of `l` in the loop, or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, splitting won't help really.

You could use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and dynamic [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

lst = [["lsn","tid","status","type","item","AFIM","BFIM"],
       [1,1,"Active","Read","X","-","-"],
       [2,1,"Active","Write","X","2","0"]]

Data = namedtuple('Data', lst[0])
rows = [Data(*row) for row in lst[1:]]
print [data for data in rows if data.tid == 1 and data.type == 'Write']

# Prints [Data(lsn=2, tid=1, status='Active', type='Write', item='X', AFIM='2', BFIM='0')]
```

#### Notes

- As someone's already mentioned, better not to call variables after builtins like `list` - it leads to confusion or bugs usually.